# .NET Core solution red code but builds

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017, .net-core-2.0

I have .NET Core solution (2.0) . I have an issue that most of code have red color. 
However solution build suceesfully.

What did I do already:

- Remove bin&obj
- Clean & Rebuild
- Removed Temporary ASP.NET Files from Temp folder
- Cleaned cache of resharper
- Removed repository and cloned again
- Restart computer
- Restart computer + leave room + coffe

None of above solution is working.

Does somone have any repair strategy ?:)

Comment: What ReSharper version do you use? If you disable ReSharper (Tools | Options | ReSharper Ultimate | Suspend Now), will the red code disappear from the code editor?

Comment: Indeed resharper update fixed the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed as Alexander Kurakin posted, there was issue with Resharper. I have updated R# and it worked :)